# extract values of ping message

Tags: java, android, string, ping

I am working on an application on android that performs ping requests (via android shell) and I read from the console the message displayed. A typical message is the following

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=186 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=46 time=209 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 186.127/197.891/209.656/11.772 ms
```

I store the above message in a String. I want to extract the values of the time, for example 186 and 209 and also the percentage for loss, 0 (in this case).

I was thinking to go through the string and look the values after "time=". However I don't know how to do it.
How can I manipulate the string I have in order to extract the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by getting each line of the string:

```
String[] lines = pingResult.split("\n");
```

Then, loop and use substring.

```
for (String line : lines) {
    if (!line.contains("time=")) continue;
    // Find the index of "time="
    int index = line.indexOf("time=");

    String time = line.substring(index + "time=".length());
    // do what you will
}
```

If you want to parse to an `int`, you could additionally do:

```
int millis = Integer.parseInt(time.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
```

This will remove all non-digit characters

You can do something similar for the percentage:

```
for (String line : lines) {
    if (!line.contains("%")) continue;

    // Find the index of "received, "
    int index1 = line.indexOf("received, ");

    // Find the index of "%"
    int index2 = line.indexOf("%");

    String percent = line.substring(index1 + "received, ".length(), index2);
    // do what you will
}
```